# Decode the Input parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, urlencode, json-deserialization

I am trying to decode the input parameter which is URL encoded.

The input parameter looks like this

```
json=%7B%0A%22MouseSampleBarcode%22%20%3A%20%22MOS81%22%0A%7D%0A
```

I have this model class:

```
public class CoreBarCodeDTO
{
    private string _json;
    public string json
    {
        get { return _json; }
        set
        {
            string decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value);
            _json = decoded;
        }
    }

}
```

In my controller I am trying to parse this and trying to retrieve the `MouseSampleBarCode`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] CoreBarCodeDTO coreBarCode)
{
    string inputJson = coreBarCode.json;

    dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(inputJson);
    string Bar_Code = results.MouseSampleBarcode;
```

When I try to debug this using fiddler

[image]

I am getting this error

> System.NullReferenceException: An error has occurred
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Equalsk Yes I did take a look at that thread. But this is something specific to the URL encoding

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: @AdrianWragg when it reaches `string inputJson = coreBarCode.json;` it throws this error

Comment: So there's no enough information to help you. Did you put the breakpoint at the `set` method of the `json` property? the `value` variable on it is being setted with the expected string? In wich line of the code the exception was thrown?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with those informations or it will be downvoted

Comment: `But this is something specific to the URL encoding` - No it isn't. I would guess that `coreBarCode` is `null`.

Comment: @xyz Then you're chasing the wrong problem - and now you can work on getting a minimal, verifiable example that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I do have a breakpoint in the set method but it doesnot even reach there before throwing the error

Comment: @Equalsk coreBarCode is null when I debug. I am not sure what is that = I am missing here.

Comment: @xyz it mean the problem is in your request. The `Post` method isn't getting a `CoreBarCodeDTO` parameter

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Yeah I see that. Should I change the content type in the Fiddler?

Comment: I guess it should be like `coreBarCode={ json='yourContent'}` but I'm not sure about it. I'll let someone more familiar with json/webrequest to aswer it **after you edit your question and ask for the right problem**

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Thanks for your effort I got it working it is just the content type in Fiddler. The code is all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue it is in the Fiddler I gave the wrong Content Type

It should be

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```